# Create an IOS application without using App-Store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes

I would like to create an IPhone application for my company co-workers.

This application should not be public, so I don't want to upload it to the App-Store. And Apple may reject my app from the Store, because it may not tally the App Review: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/

How is it possible?

Comment: Great for you and your question being?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the question. Edited it

Comment: If you have less than 50 co-worker devices, then Ad Hoc distribution might work.  No need to submit to the App store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create Archive
- Export for Ad Hoc Development
- Distribute by uploading it using testflightapp.com

It also doesn't need a `Distribution Profile`, however a `Developer Profile` is required

Answer (score 1):

You can distribute your application using Apple Enterprise development program.Please review more details on this link:https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Answer (score 1):

You could also try an Ad-Hoc distribution:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW4

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Apple Developer License you can use TestFlight / the prerelease function of iTunes Connect, see here:

[image: Prerelease in iTunes Connect]

Answer (score 1):

When my company asked me to develop something that we could use to distribute our apps to clients for testing they told me we couldn't use [TestflightApp](https://www.testflightapp.com/dashboard/) (Before Apple purchased it) so I developed our own in-house distribution service. As long as you have a server setup its super easy to put it all together here is the [Apple Documentation for creating your own Over the air distribution service or OTA](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/iPhoneOTAConfiguration.pdf). Otherwise if you don't want to or don't feel the need to I'd recommend just using [Apples pre-release service Testflight](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html) which can be accessed through iTunesconnect OR you could use the still active (but owned by Apple) the [original TestflightApp](https://www.testflightapp.com/dashboard/), though Apple could just flip the switch on this any day since they now have the version in iTunesconnect.